# Zerobrane Isn't Searching My Current Project Folder

Tags: zerobrane

I've been using Zerobrane for a long time on a project, and the Find in Files works fine for that project. However, if I then open another file from another folder project, and then slick the switch to project of current file button, it properly allows me to see all my files in the new project. However, when I try and Find in Files, it doesn't check the proper folder. In fact, it doesn't check the old project, either. It simply always gives no results for a Find in Files search. Does anyone know how?

Comment: Troy, I can't reproduce this issue; what folder does the Find toolbar show when you switch to the second folder?

Comment: This might be a better fit for SuperUser.